# How do I use external crates in Rust?

Tags: libraries, rust

I'm trying to work with the [rust-http](https://github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http) library, and I'd like to use it as the basis for a small project.

I have no idea how to use something that I can't install via `rustpkg install <remote_url>`. In fact, I found out today that `rustpkg` is now deprecated.

If I `git clone` the library and run the appropriate `make` commands to get it built, how do I use it elsewhere? I.e. how do I actually use `extern crate http`?

Comment: Small note: `extern mod` has been recently renamed to `extern crate`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Update

For modern Rust, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50307802/1043806) answer.

---

## Original answer

You need to pass the `-L` flag to `rustc` to add the directory which contains the compiled **http** library to the search path. Something like `rustc -L path-to-cloned-rust-http-repo/build your-source-file.rs` should do.

[Tutorial reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20140402184000/https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/tutorial.html#a-minimal-example)

Comment: Note: Add the **directory**, not the file! Say you have libhttp.dylib in the directory ../rust-http/target/debug, then build with `rustc -L ../rust-http/target/debug your-source-file.rs`.

Comment: This answer is correct, but almost no modern user of Rust will follow these instructions. Instead, prefer to [use Cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50307802/155423).

Answer (score 42):

Since Rust 1.0, 99% of all users will use [Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/) to manage the dependencies of a project. The TL;DR of the documentation is:

1. Create a project using `cargo new`
2. Edit the generated `Cargo.toml` file to add dependencies:

   ```
   [dependencies]
   old-http = "0.1.0-pre"
   ```
3. Access the crate in your code:

   **Rust 2021 and 2018**

   ```rust
   use old_http::SomeType;
   ```

   **Rust 2015**

   ```rust
   extern crate old_http;
   use old_http::SomeType;
   ```
4. Build the project with `cargo build`

Cargo will take care of managing the versions, building the dependencies when needed, and passing the correct arguments to the compiler to link together all of the dependencies.

Read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html) for further details on getting started with Cargo. [Specifying Dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) in the Cargo book has details about what kinds of dependencies you can add.

Comment: `extern crate` is still useful in modern Rust when combined with `macro_use`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html?highlight=macro_use#the-macro_use-attribute

Comment: @hkBst any reasonably maintained / updated crate will expose macros that can be imported using the normal `use ...` syntax. I haven't _needed_ to use `#[macro_use]` for several years now.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Might it be useful to add something about this in the `macro_use` reference?

Comment: Nowadays, would you instead use `cargo add old-http` to add a crate to a project?

Answer (score 4):

*Not related to your post, but it is to your title. Also, cargo based.*

**Best practice:**

1. external crate named `foo`

```
use ::foo;
```

2. module (which is part of your code/crate) named `foo`

```
use crate::foo;
```

In both the cases, you can use `use foo;` instead, but it can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've built it, you can use the normal `extern crate http;` in your code. The only trick is that you need to pass the appropriate `-L` flag to `rustc` to tell it where to find `libhttp`.

If you have a submodule in your project in the `rust-http` directory, and if it builds into its root (I don't actually know where `make` in `rust-http` deposits the resulting library), then you can build your own project with `rustc -L rust-http pkg.rs`. With that `-L` flag, the `extern crate http;` line in your `pkg.rs` will be able to find `libhttp` in the `rust-http` subfolder.

Comment: how to run rustc with rand pls? `rustc -L rust-rand` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. I ended up doing this in my Cargo.toml

```sh
[dependencies]
shell = { git = "https://github.com/google/rust-shell" }
```

Then in my main.rs I was able to add this and compile with success.  Note that this cargo package is a macro in my case. Often you will not want to have the #[macro_use] before the extern call.

```sh
#[macro_use] extern crate shell;
```

Comment: See more info https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html. Your able to point to branches and tags as well instead of the latest current branch.